# Posicionamiento de elementos en pie de página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy en un parcial y me debería de quedar el pie de página así:

[image: como me deberia quedar.]
Pero a mí me queda así:

[image: Mi diseño]

Acá dejo mi código:

```css
#pie {
  background-color: #000000;
  clear: both;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #424242;
}

h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#ultimamoda {}

img.ulmoda {
  border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
  padding: 6px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

p.ulmoda {
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#horoscopo {
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px 20px 90px 90px;
}

img.ih {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#contactanos {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px 110px 110px 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pie">

  <!-- pie de pagina -->

  <div id="ultimamoda">
    <h3>La ultima Moda!!!</h3>
    <hr align="left" width="300"> </hr>
    <img class="ulmoda" src="images/moda.jpg">
    <p class="ulmoda"> Rompe la monotía de los <br> colores apagados y aburridos y <br> llena tu armario del color de <br> moda de este verado 2011: el <br> naranja. ¡No te pierdas la<br> galeria! Moda en color naranja..<br>
      <a href=””>leer nota>></a>
    </p>
  </div>


  <div id="horoscopo">
    <p> Horoscopo </p>
    <hr align="left" width="200"> </hr>
    <img class="ih" src="images/h1.jpg">
    <img class="ih" src="images/h2.jpg">
    <img class="ih" src="images/h3.jpg"><br>
    <img class="ih" src="images/h4.jpg">
    <img class="ih" src="images/h5.jpg">
    <img class="ih" src="images/h6.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="contactanos">

    <p> contactenos! <br>
      <hr align="left" width="200"> </hr>
      Razón social <br> Dirección: <br> Ciudad: <br> CP:
      <br> tel: xxxx xxxxx xxxxx <br> Fax: xxxx xxxxx xxxxx <br> Email: info@web.com <br> Link: <a HREF>Mi empresa</A>
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la propiedad de flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS). Flexbox te permite ordenar los elementos hijos del selector en el que escribas la propiedad en fila o columnas y además le puedas dar una alineación según te convenga. Un ejemplo sería:

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.elemento {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="elemento">
    <h1>Ejemplo 1</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Esto es un parrafo de ejemplo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="elemento">
    <h1>Ejemplo 2</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Esto es un parrafo de ejemplo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="elemento">
    <h1>Ejemplo 3</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Esto es un parrafo de ejemplo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que el texto quede como el del ejemplo, se debe agregar el justificado con la etiqueta P ALIGN="justify" en el parrafo del class "ulmoda", y para el texto con la etiqueta br cambiala por p, el tamaño se arregla en el codigo en css con px, asi deberia de quedar mas parecido.